# PHP scan folders then files while echoing

Tags: php, recursion, directory

I've been trying to print out files in a list, getting both files, folders and subfolders.
I can get everything out, but I want to display folders first.
Is there a way to do this?

My code so far:

```
function getFiles($path) {
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {
            if($file->isDot()) continue;

            if($file->isDir())
                echo "<li class='folder'>\n";
            else
                echo "<li>\n";

                echo "<a href='#'>" . $file->getFilename() . "</a>\n";
            if ($file->isDir()) {
                echo "<ul>\n";
                getFiles($file->getPathname());
                echo "</ul>\n";
            }
            echo "</li>\n";

    }
}
```

Hope you can help me out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `echo` add them to a temporary array. I would create an array name `$directories` and an array named `$files` you can then loop through those two arrays and `echo`.

Something like this:

```
function getFiles($path) {
    $directories = array();
    $files = array();
    foreach (new DirectoryIterator($path) as $file) {
        if ($file->isDot())
            continue;

        if ($file->isDir())
            $directories[] = $file;
        else
            $files[] = $file;
    }
    foreach($directories as $file) {
        echo "<li class='folder'>\n";
            echo "<a href='#'>" . $file->getFilename() . "</a>\n";
            echo "<ul>\n";
            getFiles($file->getPathname());
            echo "</ul>\n";
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
    foreach($files as $file) {
        echo "<li>\n";
            echo "<a href='#'>" . $file->getFilename() . "</a>\n";
        echo "</li>\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I then be able to echo files inside folders recursivly?